# Ajax not working with wunderground API (A Weather service to get information and display)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, wunderground

Hello there!.

I am trying to use a public api from wunderground (more info in [http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML][1]) on a web page (in fact in a widget for a phone, but for testing purposes, but is the same technically speaking and writing code).

The main question is that i haven't been able to get the ajax request work, i try using a plain request (without any library) and request using jquery; as you can guess: no one works.

I am getting really frustrating with this. I know there is ton of info ajax, but unfortunately i only get more frustrating understanding less i doesn't find one concrete answer over a sea of information (like the internet).

Maybe one charity soul :) can help me, i copy paste the code: is to simple to only see and for test you only have to copy and paste.

Well that is all, thanks to all!.
Grettings.
Víc

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Data</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function tryGet ()
        {
            try
            {
                var xhr = XMLHttpRequest ();
                xhr.open("GET","http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=SABE",true);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
                    {
                        if (xhr.status == 200) 
                        {
                            alert(xhr);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            ret = "Error code " + xhr.status;
                            alert(ret);
                        }
                    }
                }
                xhr.send(null);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        function tryGet2 ()
        {
            //Let's fetch simple.xml using jQuery ajax request
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=SABE", 
                dataType: "xml", 
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="try get" onclick="tryGet()"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="try get 2" onclick="tryGet2()"/>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- To put things when things works fine-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't call external URLs, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids it. It really stinks that no browser is able to spell this out in a clear error message.

Comment: Yes but it is a public api, i mean... it should be public and allow querying using ajax without a proxy server... don't you thing that?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is

1   create a server side proxy

2   call the proxy through ajax and the proxy will in turn call the weather service

3   get the xml response form the proxy

4   parse it and display it

here is how you do it in php

create a file weather.php and put the following code in it

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$url = "http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/WXCurrentObXML/index.xml?query=SABE";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
echo $str;
?>
```

call weather.php from the client side like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',  
    url:'path/to/weather.php',  
    cache:false,
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(data){         
     xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data),
     $xml = $(xmlDoc),
     $credit = $xml.find('credit').text();
     alert($credit); // alerts Weather Underground NOAA Weather Station
    },
    error:function(jxhr,e){
        console.log(jxhr.status);
        console.log(e.responseText);
    }
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: thanks Enigma for your quick answer! I will keep this in mind. But i really think that there must be a way to use the public api without this workaround. I mean.. is a PUBLIC api, so the server must has the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, don't you think that?

Answer (score 1):

On the front end, you can use a callback, heres my way of grabbing stations using the WU search:

```
var get_city_list =  function(query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?cb=cb_func&query=" + query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        callback: "cd_func"
    });
}

    window.cb_func = function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(indexInArray, value) {
        $.each(value, function(idx, result) {
            $("<li>")
            .data("name", result.name)
            .addClass("weather-station")
            .text(result.name)
            .appendTo("#search-results");
        });
    });
}
```