# No responding of request from client to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I try to make a request from client to server using Jquery and Ajax, but it doesn't work. I even tried Ajax and Xml, but still not working. Can somebody help me for this issue ?
Here is my code. For sure that jquery-1.6.2.js is on same directory than .html file, also client and server are connected at same internet network.

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      $("div").load('http://myIPserver/isrhiproxy/isr_stm_info.aspx?requestType=101&query=20110823;1435;53173;any;139;n');
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Horaire Bus 139</div>
<button>Voir</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an absolute URI which suggests you are trying to violate the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) about which there [are many questions and answers](http://www.google.co.uk/search?cx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bypass+same+origin+policy#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=bypass+same+origin+policy+site%3astackoverflow.com&pbx=1&oq=bypass+same+origin+policy+site%3astackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6079l7542l0l7695l9l7l0l0l0l1l187l694l5.2l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=80a9548917d021a&biw=1090&bih=578) already.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax request to a .php script on same server  that does the cross domain request for you and returns the result. Look up cURL.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin has explained why you are not getting the response what you can do is make a server side proxy send an ajax request to your proxy. The proxy will in-turn call the web service you are trying to access and return the response to your ajax call. Here is an example [Ajax not working with wunderground API (A Weather service to get information and display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134163/ajax-not-working-with-wunderground-api-a-weather-service-to-get-information-and/7134433#7134433)